# Does OpenVPN support HTTP proxy over SSL (HTTPS)

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy, openvpn, ssl, http-proxy

I'm trying to use the HTTP proxy functionality of OpenVPN over HTTPS, but it is not working. If I use HTTP (PlainText) it works, but I prefer to use it over HTTPS, for security reasons.

Is this supported, by OpenVPN? I could not find information on whether this is supported by OpenVPN or not.

I'm using apache as forward proxy.

This is the working setup:

```
openvpn2 --config config.ovpn --http-proxy proxy.example.com 80 basic --verb 6
```

And the same thing with port 443 over SSL does not work:

```
openvpn2 --config config.ovpn --http-proxy proxy.example.com 80 basic --verb 6
```

And gives the following error:

```
2022-01-17 19:38:59.302564 [LOG] TCP recv EOF
2022-01-17 19:38:59.302754 [LOG] Proxy Error: on proxy.example.com:443: HTTP proxy unexpected EOF: reply incomplete
2022-01-17 19:38:59.303023 [LOG] Proxy connection error:on proxy.example.com:443: HTTP proxy unexpected EOF: reply incomplete
```

I Have verified that the HTTPS/SSL proxy works correctly as follows:

1. Start a netcat listen on port 1194

```
nc -l 1194
```

2. Connect to the listening netcat trough the proxy:

```
openssl s_client -crlf -connect proxy.example.com:443
....
<SSL DATA>
....
---
read R BLOCK
CONNECT <netcat_ip>:1194 HTTP/1.0
Proxy-Authorization: Basic BASE64_ENCODED_BASIC_AUTH==

HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
Proxy-agent: Apache/2.4.41

hello
```

And I correctly get the 'hello' text in netcat.

The SSL certificate is OK and is issued by a well-known CA.

I'd be very happy if anyone can provide any help/information on this.

Thanks!

Comment: HTTPS proxies are exotic. You won’t find many programs supporting them. The OpenVPN connection already is encrypted. More encryption will only add more overhead.

Comment: Thank you @DanielB for your comment!
You are right about the encryption overhead. 
I Just wanted to use HTTPS for better security on the initial connection :)